# How can I get a scatterplot on Excel to link to my PowerPoint and change as I update the data?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

I have a full-automated powerpoint that updates as I go into my excel data and change the numbers. The only issue i'm having is that the scatterplots don't update on their own and I have to manually paste them in. It turns out that powerpoint doesn't support scatterplots updating, so I'll have to create a Macro to do it. Does anyone have experience with this or VBA code to help out? Any ideas are welcome.

I already have a macro that links my powerpoint to the specific excel sheet i'm working on with all the charts. But not one to help automate the scatterplots.

Comment: https://slidetutorials.com/how-to-update-charts-in-powerpoint-from-excel-automatically/#:~:text=Select%20your%20chart%20in%20PowerPoint,then%20the%20Refresh%20Data%20button.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the correct pasting action when bringing the plot from Excel to Powerpoint:

1. In Excel, copy the whole plot
2. In powerpoint do not `Ctrl-v` but instead right-click, then choose `Keep source formatting and link data` (or similar, this is translated from German version, ).